# Can I do exercise and dumbbells at home during swami ayappa diksha?

Tags: ayyappa

Most of Hindu sites and devotees giving different replies to this question. please give correct answer. I have habit of exercises and dumbbells at home(**not gym**).

Diksha name: swami Ayyappa diskha

Days: 41

I know most of the North Indians don't know about this Deeksha thing.

Comment: I don't see why not as long as you do it meditatively and while remembering your deeksha devata.

Comment: Generally, while doing a Deeksha, personal care like combing hair, applying oil, shamppo is not allowed. You can ask a Guru swami near you. They can advice you correctly.

Comment: You are also not allowed to shave or cut hairs, talk to women, take non-veg during these 40 days right?

Comment: @Rickross Did I mention shave or cut hairs, talk to women, take non-veg in my question? Might I ask why you comment about this things?

Comment: @NogShine Did I ask about combing hair, applying oil, shampoo? Might I ask why you comment about this things?

Comment: Yes u can ask. I asked about those things because i have heard about them. So i was curious to know. And who is better to ask  than someone who is taking up the Ayappa vrata himself? So, am i right or wrong? @user12721

Comment: It is beyond absurd that he usual suspects have put this unimpeachable question on hold.

Comment: @SK That's because personal advice questions are off-topic here too :D

Comment: @Rickross - you know what the issue is - you know which clique here gets its ox gored by mention of Ayyappa.  the question is 1000 pct a question on hinduism.

Comment: I know it belongs to Hinduism, the problem is that the question is framed as if it's asking personal advice and which is not allowed on the site as per rules.So, for the Q to be re-opened it has to framed generally something like this" Can persons who took up the Ayappa Diksha exercise...?" @SK