# Can I go to gym, when I'm in ayyappa Deeksha

Tags: ayyappa

Can I go to gym when I take ayyappa Deeksha? If I can't go, may I know the reason?

Comment: Duplicate of the https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22467/can-i-do-exercise-and-dumbbells-at-home-during-swami-ayappa-diksha question or closely related...

Comment: @sarvabhouma that question is doing gym at home! Mine is going to gym, if not why?